# Coordinate display in Terrasync

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, datum, trimble, pathfinder

I'm using Terrasync on a Trimble GeoXH 6000 - set for WGS 84 and UTM. It acquires satellites fine, but instead of displaying my current location in UTMS, the skyplot screen shows "12RVU" and then a single 10 digit number. For the life of me I can't figure out what 12RVU is, or how to make it display actual coordinates. I've been using Terrasync for years and have never had a problem like this before.

Comment: You might be better asking this on http://www.gps-forums.net/ as it appears to be related to an actual device issue rather than GIS software etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks like the USNG or MGRS coordinate system, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_National_Grid and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system for further details.

12RVU indicates that you are in UTM zone 12, somehwere in Western Mexico.

You might need to read the manual on how to change the setting (I don't have the unit myself).

In the Getting Started Guide from [Trimble](http://www.trimble.com/globalTRLTAB.asp?Nav=Collection-30232) on p. 9 you will find an entry to set "Display USNG". You might disable it to get "normal" coordinates.